# stop span inside href inheriting hover styles from href

Tags: html, css

**Problem**

I need the span to not have `text-decoration: underline`. I can not change the markup in anyway. Is this possible?

**Mark Up**

```
<a href="#">
    Working test
    <span>▼</span>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover span {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: give me some love for the question :p. Good suggests thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/y2Uta/2/)**. Works in all modern browser and IE8+.

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    padding-right:16px;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
span {
    text-decoration: none;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, oddly i already have this applied. At least the a has position: rel. I obviously have other styles interfering. So i look at this properly tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not.

The problem you're going to run into is that the parent element (the anchor `<a>`) is going to have the underline anywhere the span is, as it's inside the anchor which has the underline set in CSS. If you could change the markup, you'd be able to use something like below, which applies the underline only to the part of the anchor you want underlined (wrapped in a span).

```
<a href="#"><span class="nounderline">No</span> <span class="underline">Underline</span></a>

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
span.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

But as your markup currently is, there's no way to do it.

Comment: If you have to support IE7, which many of us usually do, that solution won't be what you're after. This is a more general option. However, it looks like @j08691's solution will work for OP.